# upload file in angular 2 with nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new in angular 2 and node js.
I need to upload file in folder using anjular2 and also want to store that file name in mongodb database, at server side. For that I tried this but its not working.Using code is that:
app.component.ts:

```
        attachment: any;
       hasBaseDropZoneOver: boolean = false;
        options: Object = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload'
        };
        sizeLimit = 2000000;
        handleUpload(data): void {
        if (data && data.response) {
        this.attachment = data;
        }
        }
        fileOverBase(e:any):void {
        this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
        }
        beforeUpload(uploadingFile): void {
        console.log(uploadingFile.size + ' -- '+this.sizeLimit);
        if (uploadingFile.size > this.sizeLimit) {
        uploadingFile.setAbort();
        alert('File is too large');
        }
        }
```

this is app.html file:-

```
        <input type="file" ngFileSelect [options]="options" (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)" (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">
```

app.module.ts

```
        import { Ng2UploaderModule } from 'ng2-uploader';
```

Server Side Code:

```
        const upload = multer({
        dest: 'uploads/',
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
        }
        })
        });
        app.post('/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
        res.json(req.files.map(file => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        return {
        originalName: file.originalname,
        filename: file.filename
        }
        }));
        });
```

It is showing me below error:

```
        XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/upload. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access
```

Comment: it is about CORS

Comment: Please indent your code and make it more presentable

Comment: Make sure you are passing the correct headers from your Angular app's request and also Node's server code